# Replace one word from user input

Tags: java, input, replace, string-concatenation

For a project, I need to take a user input such as "I hate you" and I need to replace the word "hate" with "love". I can't use replace all.

I understand that I can use `.indexOf` and find the position of the word hate and then use concatenation to form a new sentence I'm just really confused on how to do that.

I'll show what I have below. Also can you guys keep in mind that I'm new to this site and programming. I'm not just here for a quick fix, I'm actually trying to learn this. I've been doing a lot of research and I can't seem to find an answer.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ReplaceLab {
    public static void main(String[]args){

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Please enter a line of text:");
        String userInput = input.nextLine();
        int position = userInput.indexOf("hello");
        System.out.println("I have rephrased that line to read");

    }
}
```

Comment: What about using `String.replaceFirst()` ?

Answer (score 0):

String.replace() will replace every ocurrance in your input String:

```
String userInput = input.nextLine();
String replaced = userInput.replace("hate", "love");// Here you have your new string
```

For example, "I hate to hate you" will become "I love to love you".

If only the first occurrence must be changed (making my example "I hate to love you") then alfasin comment is correct and String.replaceFirst() will get the job done.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to use .indexOf()

```
String find = "hate";
String replace = "love";

int pos = userInput.indexOf(find);
int pos2 = pos + find.size();

String replaced = userInput.substring(0, pos) + " " + replace + " " + userInput.substring(pos2);
```

If you are doing this make sure to check that indexOf returns a valid number.